# Use a custom classifier in Glue for multi line records

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have some files in the following format

```
AB1|STUFF|1234|

AB2|SF|STUFF|

AB1|STUFF|45670|

AB2|AF|STUFF|
```

Each bit of data is delimited by '|' and a record is made up of the data in lines AB1 and AB2.

I would like to use a custom grok classifier in Glue something like the following:

```
?<LINE1>(?:AB1)?|%{WORD:ignore1}|%{NUMBER:id}\|\n%{WORD:LINE2}|%{WORD:make}|%{WORD:stuff2}\|
```

That is a multi line grok expression to extract the data from a multi line record as shown above. I am unsure how the classifiers in Glue work any comments or advice would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Glue Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#custom-classifier-grok):

> Grok patterns can process only one line at a time. Multiple-line
> patterns are not supported. Also, line breaks within a pattern are not
> supported.

I am not sure what the actual question is, if you need general guidance on how to create your own classifier, I would advise you to read [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-classifiers.html) and [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#custom-classifier-grok).

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear , I was indeed meaning to ask if multi line grok patterns would work in AWS Glue classifiers. Thanks for the links

Comment: If the answer helped you, an upvote or accept would be appreciated